# Can not get the right data from Vue data

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I have the following code in a component

```
  data() {
    return {
      data: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$axios.get("https://canteen.sjtu.edu.cn/CARD/Ajax/Place").then(res => {
      this.data = res.data;
    });
    console.log(this.data);
  },
```

but I can not get the updated data, for example, `console.log(this.data)` has no data I want, but I can get the right data in my template

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ data }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And if I `console.log(this)` in mounted, I can get the `Vue component`, and in it I can see the data I want!

Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: The axios call is asynchronous so its callback will be called at some point in the future. The console logging line will run immediately, it won't wait for the axios call to complete. The reason you can see the data when you log `this` is because logged objects are live, not copies. When you click to expand the properties of the object you'll see the current values, not the values that were present at the point you logged it.

Comment: @skirtle Can you give me a solution, thanks a lot

Comment: Move the console log line so that it's inside the `then` callback, immediately after you assign `this.data`.

Comment: @skirtle Yeah, thanks a lot, I think I have found the solution to solve my problem, and in fact console log line is just for test, but thank you all the same~~